# Convert all Text Documents from a folder to PDF

Tags: python, fpdf, pyfpdf

I have few text documents in a folder and would like to convert them to PDF Format. I am able to do it individually with the below code. Is there any way to select all the text files from a folder, convert and save them with the original name (as it was for text documents)? Below is the code I used to convert each file:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 8)

f = open("C:\\Users\\rc06587\\Desktop\\Text Doc\\Sample\\New folder (2)\\exp_000004593_cn23rk__09042020000000_citrixsystemsinc_92080217mr_00384.TXT", "r")

for x in f:
    pdf.cell(10, 4, txt = x, ln = 1, align = 'L')

pdf.output("exp_000004593_cn23rk__09042020000000_citrixsystemsinc_92080217mr_00384.TXT.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.listdir()` to get the files in the directory you want, filter for text files, and then do your conversion.

```py
from fpdf import FPDF

def convert_one_file(path):
    pdf = FPDF()

    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 8)

    f = open(path, "r")

    for x in f:
        pdf.cell(10, 4, txt = x, ln = 1, align = 'L')

    pdf.output(path + ".PDF")
    
path = "..."
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.sep.join((path, f))) and f.endswith(".txt"):
        convert_one_file(os.sep.join((path, f)))
```

A more elegant solution would probably be to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to join the paths.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering this. I am ending up with an error -- 

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rc06587\Documents\TexttoPDF\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    if os.path.isfile(os.sep.join(path, f)) and f.endswith(".txt"):
TypeError: str.join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)"

Inputs on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, `.join()` takes a list/tuple, not multiple items. Use `os.sep.join((path, f))` instead.

Comment: Sorry. I am completely new to this. Could you help with the code. Below is the code am currently using:
import os
from fpdf import FPDF


def convert_one_file(path):
    pdf = FPDF()

    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=8)

    f = open(path, "r")

    for x in f:
        pdf.cell(10, 4, txt=x, ln=1, align='L')

    pdf.output(path + ".PDF")


path = "C:\\Users\\rc06587\\Desktop\\Text Doc\\Sample\\New folder (2)\\"
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.sep.join(path, f)) and f.endswith(".txt"):
        convert_one_file(os.sep.join(path, f))

Comment: I got it using the below code:

import os
from fpdf import FPDF


def convert_one_file(path):
    pdf = FPDF()

    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=8)

    f = open(path, "r")

    for x in f:
        pdf.cell(10, 4, txt=x, ln=1, align='L')

    pdf.output(path + ".PDF")


path = "C:\\Users\\rc06587\\Desktop\\New folder (2)\\"
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.sep.join((path, f))):
        convert_one_file(os.sep.join((path, f)))

But the issue is the output is file is in PDF format but being saved as ".txt" at the end. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In windows you dont need python or fpdf just use the command line

[image]

set any command line desired to rotate through file list and write them to pdf
adapt any cmd to suit. If text is plain, it will become a searchable text.pdf

***AllTXT2PDF.cmd***

```
FORFILES /M *.txt /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE write.exe /pt @file \"Microsoft Print to PDF\" \"Microsoft Print to PDF\" \"@file.pdf\""
```

However as plain text it will be left set default size courier font so for Arial 8 point you need to save as rich text, which is easy enough if you want to style the contents for centering justify colour mixed fonts etc.

[image]

[image]